# Measure Theory: How to compute the conditional expectation of max of dice tosses?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

> Consider a dice with $f$ faces and let $(X_n)_{1 \le n \le N}$ be the outcomes of the tosses. For $1 \le n \le N$ we set $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and additionally $\mathcal{F}_0 = \{\emptyset, \Omega \}$. Consider the RVs $Z_0 := 0$ and $Z_n := \max_{1 \le k \le n} X_k \quad (1 \le n \le N)$.
>
> Compute the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(Z_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1})$ for $(1 \le n \le N)$.

I understand that intuitively $Z_n$ describes precisely the maximum number yielded by the $n$th dice toss when we know the results of the previous $n-1$ tosses. I furthermore suppose that we can model this setting as a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ via $\Omega := \{1,\ldots,f\}$ and consider $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ as uniformly distributed independent canonical RVs, i.e. $X_i(\omega) := \omega$. For the $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{A}$ I suppose it is best to set $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. However, I do not see how to transfer my "continuous" definition (see below) of condtional expectation $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$ over to this discrete case.

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X$ be a real RV with $E(\lvert X \rvert) < \infty$. $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$ is uniquely defined as a RV via the conditions
>
> 1. $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$ is $\mathcal{F}$ measurable,
> 2. $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$
> 3. $\int_A \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) d \mathbb{P} = \int_A X d \mathbb{P}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

Could you please help me?

Comment: That's a very useful and important exercise. What is $A$ in the definition of the conditional expectation?

Comment: By the way, $Z_n$ is simply the maximum (not an expectation, it is the actual, random, outcome), exactly as defined: $Z_n=\max_kX_k$.

Comment: @Matija: Thanks for your comments, I made an edit to my question.

Comment: Follow-up: In this example we can explicitly write down $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. What is it?

Comment: If I am not mistaken: $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = \{ \emptyset, \Omega, \{ X_1,\ldots,X_n \}, \Omega \setminus \{ X_1,\ldots,X_n \} \}$.

Comment: The elements $E$ of $\mathcal F_n$ are subsets $E\subseteq\Omega$. One example of an event is $E=\{\omega\in\Omega:X_1(\omega)=1\}$, which is sometimes written as $E=\{X_1=1\}$. The random variable $X_1:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is not an element of $\Omega$. I'll give you a hint: We have $\mathcal F_1=\{\{X_1\in E\}:E\subseteq\{1,\dots,f\}\}$. Can you explain why?

Comment: At first impression, I think the most we can do is express the expectation as a sum of functions of $Z_{n-1}$. Where is this question from? @3nondatur

Comment: @Snoop: This is a problem from my class.

Comment: @Matija: I edited my question a bit. I think that $\mathcal{F}_1 = \{\{X_1 \in E \} : E \subseteq \{1,\ldots,f\} \}$ follows directly by the definition of $\sigma$-Algebra generated by a RV, which I just reread.

Comment: The $n=2$, $f=4$ case is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2755966/215011

Comment: The link is great! Still, I would really recommend to go through many examples of (simple, finite) $\sigma$-algebras, look at the probability measures defined on these, random variables, then through conditional probabilities for these simple examples, then conditional expectations, and only then to come back to the general definition of conditional expectation. First thing then is to make the connection to the simple cases. If you don't have an intuition for these notions, it's impossible to work with them.

Comment: I came across this post, hope it helps: (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451793/random-variables-and-sigma-algebras)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$Z_n = \max(\underbrace{\max_{k \leq n-1} X_{k}}_{Z_{n-1}}, X_n)$$

$Z_{n-1}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurable and $X_n$ and $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ are independent. So in
$$E[Z_n\vert \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = E[\max(Z_{n-1}, X_n)\vert \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$$
we can treat $Z_{n-1}$ as a constant and integrate out $X_n$ using its unconditional distribution.

$$E[\max(Z_{n-1}, X_n)\vert \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = \frac{1}{f}\sum_{i=1}^f\max(Z_{n-1},i)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Intuitive explanation**

The quantity $E[Z_n\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$ answers the question, "Given the results of the first $n-1$ die rolls, what is the expected value of the maximum of the first $n$ rolls?" It should be further clear that the only relevant information from the first $n-1$ rolls we need is the previous maximum, $Z_{n-1}$.

There are two things that can occur. If $X_n\le Z_{n-1}$, then the maximum is unchanged, i.e. $Z_n=Z_{n-1}$. Otherwise, $X_n>Z_{n-1}$. Conditional on $X_n>Z_{n-1}$, the variable $X_n$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $\{Z_{n-1}+1,Z_{n-1}+2,\dots,f\}.$ The expectation of such a uniform variable is
$$
\frac{(Z_{n-1}+1)+f}{2}
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}
E[Z_n\mid \F_{n-1}]=
\underbrace{\frac{Z_{n-1}}{f}}_
{\substack{\text{Probability }} \\ \text{that $X_{n}\le Z_{n-1}$}}
\cdot Z_{n-1}+
\underbrace{\left(1-\frac{Z_{n-1}}{f}\right)}_{\substack{\text{Probability }} \\ \text{that $X_{n}> Z_{n-1}$}}
\frac{(Z_{n-1}+1)+f}{2}
\end{align}