# Measure Theory: How to prove that max of dice tosses is a Markov process?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-process

This is a follow-up to [my former question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545334/measure-theory-how-to-compute-the-conditional-expectation-of-max-of-dice-tosses/4545806#4545806):

> Consider a dice with $f$ faces and let $(X_n)_{1 \le n \le N}$ be the outcomes of the tosses. For $1 \le n \le N$ we set $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and additionally $\mathcal{F}_0 = \{\emptyset, \Omega \}$. Consider the RVs $Z_0 := 0$ and $Z_n := \max_{1 \le k \le n} X_k \quad (1 \le n \le N)$.
>
> Show that for any real-valued function $g$ it holds $\mathbb{E}(g(Z_n) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = 
>  \mathbb{E}(g(Z_n) \mid Z_{n-1})$

I understand that intuitively $Z_n$ describes precisely the maximum number yielded by the $n$th dice toss when we know the results of the previous $n-1$ tosses. I furthermore suppose that we can model this setting as a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ via $\Omega := \{1,\ldots,f\}$ and consider $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ as uniformly distributed independent canonical RVs, i.e. $X_i(\omega) := \omega$. For the $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{A}$ I suppose it is best to set $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. My definition of conditional expectation is as follows:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X$ be a real RV with $E(\lvert X \rvert) < \infty$. $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$ is uniquely defined as a RV via the conditions
>
> 1. $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$ is $\mathcal{F}$ measurable,
> 2. $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$
> 3. $\int_A \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) d \mathbb{P} = \int_A X d \mathbb{P}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

My idea would have been to show that $\mathcal{F}_{n-1} = \sigma({Z}_{n-1})$, however, I doubt that this is true. Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $Z_n=\max(Z_{n-1},X_n)$ and $X_n$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$ and $Z_{n-1}$ is $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$-measurable. [So](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768648/a-question-about-conditional-expectations?noredirect=1) $E[f(Z_n)|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]=E[f(\max(X_n,z))]|_{z=Z_{n-1}}=g(Z_{n-1})$. But, equivalently, $E[f(Z_n)|Z_{n-1}]=g(Z_{n-1})$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to clearify: $\mathbb{E}[g(Z_n)|Z_{n-1}]=g(Z_{n-1})$ and $\mathbb{E}[g(\max(X_n,z))]|_{z=Z_{n-1}}=g(Z_{n-1})$ holds, because $Z_n$ and $Z_{n-1}$ are independent?

Comment: @3nondatur $X_n$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$. $g$, in my post, is a way to indicate that the cond. expectation is a function of $Z_{n-1}$, and such function coincides for both conditional expectations for arbitrary measurable $f$, making the process Markov

Answer (score 1):

As far as the event $\{Z_1=k_1,Z_2=k_2,\ldots ,Z_{n-1}=k_{n-1}\}$ have positive measure, you have that

$$\Pr [Z_n=k|Z_1=k_1,Z_2=k_2,\ldots ,Z_{n-1}=k_{n-1}]=\Pr [Z_n=k|Z_{n-1}=k_{n-1}]$$

Therefore $\{Z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Markov chain.∎